# Are there any online demo's of AsciiDoc editors demonstrating live preview?

Tags: editor, demo, asciidoc, live-preview

I have come across many demo's of `Markdown` editors demonstrating live preview eg:

http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/dingus

http://dillinger.io/

http://www.markitdown.net/markdown

http://epiceditor.com/

http://hallojs.org/demo/markdown/

But I haven't been able to find much searching for `AsciiDoc Editor live preview`.

I have come across articles on setting up such functionality eg:

http://asciidoctor.org/docs/editing-asciidoc-with-live-preview/

but I am really just after some online demo's, are there any out there?

Comment: Take a look at the Asciidoctor project, f.ex. AsciiDocBox: https:/github.com/espadrine/AsciiDocBox .

Comment: [www.gitbook.com](http://www.gitbook.com) has support asciidoc. So you can edit and preview the result online.

Answer (score 6):

The *AsciiDoctor.js Live Preview* browser extension may suit your needs:

> Render AsciiDoc (.ad, .adoc, .asc, .asciidoc) as HTML inside Chrome!

1. Install it for either [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/asciidoctorjs-live-previe/iaalpfgpbocpdfblpnhhgllgbdbchmia) or [FireFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/asciidoctorjs-live-preview/).
2. For Chrome, you'll likely want to enable *Allow access to local file URLs* under the extension options.
3. Then either point your browser at a remote AsciiDoc URL or create a new file locally (e.g. `helloworld.adoc`), enter some text in it with your favourite editor, and then point your browser to it (e.g. `file:///home/leif/helloworld.adoc`).

Comment: Asciidoctor.js Live Preview  is great! It provides a button that toggles between the source-text-view and the asciidoc-rendered view. Ideally the button would be replaced with a split screen view that lets one see both the source and the target of asciidoc (similar to the view that you get on stackoverflow when you're posting a question or an answer). It's puzzling that this question was marked "closed" for a topic as important for software documentation as asciidoc. I suppose some people neither comment nor document their code.

Answer (score 3):

This might be what you're looking for https://github.com/lordofthejars/asciidoctor-markitup, with corresponding video demo http://youtu.be/PEvvwNc1kU8.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed only very sparse support there. For plain asciidoc support you can also use syntax highligting for gedit: http://kenjiru.ro/blog/2011/10/asciidoc-highlight-for-gedit

But in case you like experimental software: I've written a live converting asciidoc http server in python which you can access here: https://github.com/pypp/asciidoc_http_server.
(On the pro side you can easily give access to your asciidoc-files via web)